# Solving partial differential equation by form method (semigroup theory)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, semigroups-of-operators

We have the equations$\newcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}}\newcommand{\grad}{\operatorname{grad}}$

$$\rho(x)\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial^2}(t,x)=\div(A(x)\grad u+B(x)\grad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t})(t,x)-\div(\gamma(x) v(t,x))$$

$$\beta(x)\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(t,x)=\div(C(x)\grad v)(t,x)-\gamma(x).\grad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x)$$

$A,B,C$ are are diagonal matrices with strictly positive entries and $\gamma(x)$ is a real vector of length $d$ and $u,v$ are zero at the boundary.
This results in an operator

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0   & 1& 0\\\frac{1}{\rho(x)}\div A(x)\grad   &\frac{1}{\rho(x)}\div B(x) \grad&\frac{-1}{\rho(x)}\div\gamma(x)\\0   & \frac{-1}{\beta(x)}\gamma(x)\grad& \frac{1}{\beta(x)}\div C(x)\grad\end{pmatrix}$$

Now $A$ acts on $f=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^T$.We have $\dot{f}=Af$. We define 
$$(u,v)_H=\int_\Omega \nabla ~u_1 A(x)\nabla\overline{v_1}+\int_\Omega u_2\rho(x)\overline{v_2}+ \int_\Omega u_3\beta(x) \overline{v_3}$$
$${\|u\|_V}^2=\int_\Omega  u_1   \overline{u_1}+\int_\Omega u_2 \overline{u_2}+\int_\Omega u_3 \overline{u_3}$$

What is the associated form $(a,j)$ to the operator $A$?

Comment: The lecture i use is https://www.mat.tuhh.de/veranstaltungen/isem18/pdf/LectureNotes.pdf.

Comment: I want to use Theorem 5.7 page 53.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [How to use the form method to solve the partial differential equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453509) posted on [math.se].

Comment: one can use the identity $$\int_\Omega \psi \nabla\cdot\mathbf{A} ~dV=\int_{\partial\Omega} \psi \mathbf{A}\cdot~d\mathbf{S}-\int_\Omega \nabla\psi\cdot\mathbf{A}~dV$$ to handle the inner products to cancel some terms.

Comment: I dont know what j,V,H,( , )_H and ( , )_V should be

Comment: $u_1=u$ and $u_2=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ and $u_3=v$.

Comment: A,B,C are positive definite matrices

Comment: I can show that $a$ is accretive and H-elliptic